# django config file, how to configure paths based on dev or production environment

Tags: django

How do I configure my settings.py to use a different STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL based on whether or not im in a development environment or production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several ways of doing this, simplest is to import one more file (usually `local_settings.py`) and override main settings (production settings are in the main `settings.py`, local changes in `local_settings.py`)

code:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

other option is to keep several separate configuration files like `settings_prod.py`, `settings_dev.py` etc. each one having it's own set of configuration settings, but this is a nightmare to keep in sync. however moving parts of the settings to separate files (like `conf/db.py`, `conf/app_data.py`, `conf/locale.py`, `conf/logging.py` (etc.) and then importing them in the settings files helps a lot.
those settings are used by specifying `-s` or `--settings` option, with module name as a parameter (without .py part).

i've seen some extension of the second option, that set of settings was automatically chosen  depending on the environment variables/path/machine names. so there was one single `settings.py` with a code to choose which settings to load. this option is nice, so you do not need to specify `-s` all the time.

last but not least is to use `django-admin.py` instead of `manage.py`. difference between those two files are that `manage.py` is setting a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable for the specific project. but if you will have e.g. a virtualenv for your development, you can set your local `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to point to the correct settings file, and then use `django-admin.py` without need to specify config.

switching between projects should be easy too.

i'm sure that there are few more options, but at least you can see what is there :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically I have two settings.py files, local_settings.py and settings.py, the local_settings.py is to set variables that are supposed to be local to the environment. Usually db, paths, debugging settings go in here. This file is never put into version control. There is a local_settings.py.tmpl file that holds the settings that need to be set though.

Then in settings.py I have `from local_settings import *`  Note, settings.py will need to be adjusted if you use INSTALLED_APPS or any of the tuple based settings in the local_settings file. In settings.py change `INSTALLED_APPS = ()` to `INSTALLED_APPS += ()` for example.